# App keeps crashing when requiring helper methods from a different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*Please see Edit 2*

I have a `utils.js` module that contains helper methods. Whenever other modules require it, it causes the whole app to crash. For instance, in my `server.js`, I have

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const path = require("path");
const connectDb = require("./config/db");

app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// Define routes
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/posts"));

// connect to db
connectDb();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

My `posts.js` is:

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

// model
const Post = require("../../models/Post");

const { COMMENT_SAVE_ERROR, STRING } = require("../../constants/constants");
const { sendNotification, addNotificationToDb } = require("./utils/utils");

// @route  GET api/posts/test
// @desc   Test route
// @access Public
router.get("/test", async (req, res) => {
    console.log('reached')
});
```

And my `connectDb` method is:

```
const connectDb = async () => {
    try {
        console.log('connecting to mongodb');
        await mongoose.connect(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        });

        console.log("Mongo DB connected");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('unable to connect to mongodb');
        console.log('err===> ', err);
        console.log(err.message);
        //exit if failure
        process.exit(1);
    }
};
```

As it is now, when I run the app, I get an error:

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND pilled-shard-00-01-xxghh.mongodb.net
```

This is such a weird error, because if I get rid of this from `posts.js`,

```
const { sendNotification, addNotificationToDb } = require("./utils/utils");
```

It connects with no problem. What am I doing wrong here? It throws the same error if I do,

```
const {} = require("./utils/utils");
```

Is this even related to MongoDB? Am I not allowed to import functions like this?

`utils.js` exports the methods as,

```
module.exports = {
    sendNotification,
    addNotificationToDb
};
```

---

Edit:

```
const addNotificationToDb = (userId, postId, type) => {
  try {
    const newNotification = new Notification({
      userId,
      postId,
      typeOfNotification: type
    });

    newNotification.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error saving notification", err);
  }
};
```

---

Edit 2:

I've figured out the culprit. `api/utils.js` requires models, several of which `/utils/utils.js` requires. So when `server.js` does `app.use('/api/utils)`, those models are required twice (at least I think that's the culprit). I figured this out by commenting out the model requires in `utils/utils.js`. How can I circumvent this? Is my only option to require the models in `api/utils` and just pass them individually to the methods that are imported from `utils/utils.js`?

Comment: Maybe `utils.js` does some mongodb related stuff?

Comment: I added addNotificationToDb to OP

Comment: `nslookup test-shard-00-01-xxghh.mongodb.net` results in "can't find test-shard-00-01-xxghh.mongodb.net: Non-existent domain" - so the error is the fact that the domain `test-shard-00-01-xxghh.mongodb.net` doesn't exist - check the code in `./utils/utils.js` and anything it requires to see where this domain is referenced

Comment: Wrong string, I've made a change to OP

Comment: There are 3 shards and I can access them and write to them by getting rid of the utils import

Comment: then the issue is in utils/utils.js - the content of which is unknown to all but you

Comment: Ok, but then why does it also crash if I do `const {} = require("./utils/utils");`? Im not importing anything

Comment: Most likely because of something in the file utils. Destructuring should not be an issue.

Comment: I've made another edit to the post. Is that my only option? Or is this a bug with Mongoose?